# Mutants with healing factors in the X-Men movies

Tags: marvel, x-men, powers

Some mutants, notably, Wolverine have a healing ability, so they basically don't age (or don't age much) and they recover perfectly from wounds and injuries, and they can't be poisoned.

In X-Men Origins: Wolverine, we learn that

> Only Wolverine can get the adamantium because his healing ability is strong enough, whereas Sabertooth's is not strong enough.

Granted, this was written after X-Men 2, but why is it that

> Lady Deathstrike's healing factor, which must be as strong as Wolverine's since she has adamantium fingernails, doesn't heal the scar from the serum, let alone prevent the serum from working at all?

Comment: This may be no help at all, and I don't mean this as snarky nerdery, but if the question in a nutshell is "Why did the writers of X-Men Origins: Wolverine ignore something established in X2: X-Men United," the only answer I can think of is...because X-Men Origins: Wolverine is a bad movie. Rotten Tomatoes proves this as much as opinion can be proven; Wolverine has a 37% and X2 has a 88%.

Comment: @Brett I think the question is more of "Why didn't the healing factor work as it should have in X2?" or maybe more of "Did Character X's healing factor work the same as Wolverine's?"

Comment: @Xantec Yes, which can be summarized with "why did something that work in a 'good' movie not work in a 'bad' movie?" I don't think there's a real answer to this aside from the people behind X-Men Origins: Wolverine not paying attention to detail. I would love to be proven wrong. And please, no one bring up the age discrepancies between this movie and X-Men: First Class. That's a whole 'nother mess o' worms.

Comment: @Brett: This isn't about X-Men Origins ignoring X2. This is about something that happened in X2 which doesn't seem to fit on its own, but it fits even worse if you include the details from X-Men Origins.

Comment: @Mr. Shiny and New 安宇 Ah, I see, I guess the wording is just throwing me off.

Comment: Maybe it's just the comics, but isn't the explanation in the 1st spoiler block reversed?  The second person couldn't have the treatment because his powers were good enough to always purge the metal.  The first person's ability wasn't as strong, so the metal stuck.  That why when the first person (temporarily) lost the metal, his ability "supercharged," since it was no longer fighting the metal all the time.

Comment: @CTMacUser I'm a few years out-of-date on my comic universe explanation for the details. They must have changed it for the movie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the comics, Deathstrike was given her adamantium skeleton through magic. So was her healing factor after the skeleton was grafted.

I would assume that the serum to brainwash her isn't a virus or malignant agent which would be fought by the white blood cells of the mutant that's being effected. As to the scar, I would think that it was just movie error that they didn't think of it.

Since she died from the adamantium in X2, I would say a good explination would be that her ability to regenerate was artificial (much like it was explained in the comics, but probably not magic), since Stryker did many experiments on mutants, (and a tie in with X-Men Origins) Stryker could have recovered Wolverine's data and converted it for Deathstrike.

Comment: I dislike the "magic" answer, since there hasn't been much "magic" in the movies. I guess the serum must not be "damage", though it's been suggested elsewhere that alcohol IS "damage" and that wolverine can't really get drunk (for any length of time).

Comment: The magic reference was to the comics alone, not the movies.

Answer (score 1):

It may also be that the explanation (however out-of-"canon" or "we made it up for the movie just shut up" it might have been) ended up on the cutting room floor...much like, I've always hoped, Cyclops's death in X3 did. Very often in these big-budget comics-based movies, continuity is sacrificed in the name of expediency when scriptwriters, producers, and studio executives are all trying to keep a finger in the pie. In the end, they shove the final shooting script out the door and hope the audience doesn't look too much farther than the special effects. So the answer to your question, @MrShiney, may very well be that you shouldn't have asked it in the first place. :)